# How can I remove repeated MonthName from horizontal axis in dual axis SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am not sure whether I got duplicate MonthName or something with Sorting order. 
I have dual axis bar chart, and the problem is it displays MonthName as category for both axis. So I have duplicate MonthName. I need just one.

What expression do I need to write in order to display MonthName only lets say for Left axis?

[image]

[image]

I am sorting it by MonthNumber A to Z 
But why does it look so weird?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your **month number** is a text field and is (therefore) being sorted as text (1, 10, 11, 2, 3...). Text sorts a number by the characters from left to right like text - not by the value of the number.

Change the **Sort By** expression to

```
=CINT(Fields!MonthNumber.Value)
```

to convert to an integer for the sort.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!